# Why is it when I add an integer variable to my class function, it produces an error?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to add a variable of type `int` to my class function, but when I do, it produces an error:

> C6001 Using uninitialized memory 'vYear'

(it states this for all integer variables)

It specified I need to initialize the variable, but I want it to be initialized by the user. When I click the hint to tell me a possible fix, it specifies to initialize the variable as `int vYear{}` which as a result, adds a value of 0 when I run the program.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Most probably you have _undefined behavior, abd had that before you added anything already_, but unfortunately we can't inspect your code. At least not me, my screenreader reads out gibberish :-(

Comment: Try reading the variable before outputting it (instead of after)

Comment: In your cout statements, you use `<< vYear;` before it is set (not yet initialized, has only been declared), same for the others. Simply do not try to output at those points, as you are getting the input, there is nothing (yet) to show.

Comment: Please review [ask], in particular the part that reads "**DO NOT post images of code**". In this case, I used my browser's find-in-page feature to look for the text "vYear" in your code, but that failed. Because your code is posted as in image, when it should have been copied **as text**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read in the values for the variables *BEFORE* you then print them out, ie change this:

```cpp
cout << "Vehicle Color: " << vColor;
cin >> vColor;
```

To this instead:

```cpp
cin >> vColor;
cout << "Vehicle Color: " << vColor
```

And so on for all of the variables.